# Compare field in single row to entire column

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column of dates, and I would like to have a second column that tallies the total amount of times a date in the first column shows up over the whole column.  I am trying to use Count(IIf(...)), but I don't know how to specify that SSRS use the current row as the standard, and then check the whole column for the count.

```
Dates     Records
9/14/18   2
9/14/18   2
9/15/18   1
9/16/18   3
9/16/18   3
9/16/18   3
```

Comment: You could modify your SQL to use a `ROW_NUMBER()` function and `PARTITION BY` the date column. Then in your 'Records` column you could use the `MAX` Row_Number.

Comment: I added `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [PartTran_TranDate] ORDER BY [PartTran_TranDate] ASC) AS [Row]`, but the numbering for the first date starts at 7.  Not sure why.  Also, my `MAX()` function is returning the total maximum in the row column, not the relative one for the date.

Comment: Can't you add the row number function to your main SQL query that pulls all of the information?

Comment: I did add it to the main SQL query.

Comment: I figured out why it was starting at 7.  I was filtering my dataset.  Is there a way to apply the filter before the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using a very old version of SQL Server then you could just do something simple like

```
SELECT 
    * 
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PartTran_TranDate) AS DateCount
    FROM myTable
```

Comment: This works, now I have to figure out how to filter my results before the count...

Comment: @FredMeissner If you want to do a filter first you could just create a temp table which will put the filtered data into a temporary table for you and then you can do your count(*) over(...) on that dataset instead.

E.g
`select * INTO #MyTempTableName from myTable where <My Filter>`
So it is just your regular query and then you add `INTO #MyTempTableName` before the from clause which creates a temp table with that specified name for you to use now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help. I changed it up a little bit for simplicity:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DateCol DATE)
INSERT @Table
VALUES ('9/14/18'),
        ('9/14/18'),
        ('9/15/18'),
        ('9/16/18'),
        ('9/16/18'),
        ('9/16/18')


SELECT t.DateCol, r.rn
FROM @Table t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DateCol) rn
             FROM @Table t2
             WHERE t2.DateCol = t.DateCol
             GROUP BY t2.DateCol) r
```